# Powerpoint VSTO Ribbon Buttons Synced

Tags: c#, vsto, powerpoint

I have VSTO I've written for powerpoint 2010, I have it now functioning so that the task panes function interdependently of each other which is what I want, thanks SliverNinja for that one!

My new problem is if I have 2 Presentations open, Called them "Presentation 1" and "Presentation 2" I can now open up my task panes via a toggle button to show/hide the task pane but my problem now is if I have the task pane shown in "Presentation 2" but not one(task pane) in "Presentation 1" both buttons appear to be toggled. If I un-toggle the one on "Presentation 2" then they both become undone. So It is acting as if they are synced together.

I need some help with how to make these two buttons function as their own click events. So that they may have their own check states. I don't want to make the whole ribbon un-synced just the two buttons I have.

Answer (score 0):

Use different boolean variables to store the states of toggel buttons and taskpanes.